# Why bootrstrap 3 active class not working?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu.Please see below

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
               </div>
               <div id="navbarCollapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li><a href="#">welcome</a></li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                       </li>
                       <li><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">menu3</a></li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                           <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menu4<span class="caret"></span></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                               <li><a href="#">menu4.1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">menu4.2</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </nav>
```

I need to show active menu item as highlighted.But "active" class is not working and menu item doesn't show as active one.

Is anything missing my my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no active class in the sample so it's difficult to tell what went wrong. A common mistake is to put the class on the `a` instead of the `li`. It needs to be on the `li`. For example...

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">menu2</a></li>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/N7Jfh/)

If it still doesn't work, post the relevant CSS or create a fiddle.

Comment: I have updated your fiddle.can you please check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/N7Jfh/2/